# Using Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension method in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use the following LINQ statement to get a file name that meets certain criteria:

```
query.First( f =>
             (f.MD5 == md5 || f.ArchiveFiles.Any(af => af.MD5 == md5))
             && Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.FileName) == f.GraphicRequest.GraphicName).FileName;
```

I'm getting the following error, however:

> System.String GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL

I'm trying to compare a file name in the datatable that has its extension removed with another field. For instance, the file name in the database might be "image1.jpg" and I want to compare it to a field whose value is "image1".  I thought I could use the `Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension` method, but that doesn't appear to be the case where LINQ is concerned.

Is there another way I that I can accomplish this in LINQ?

Comment: is this entity framework?

Comment: @SamIam It is LINQ-to-SQL (using a .dbml over the tables).

Comment: Any particular reason to use dead for 6 years LINQ to SQL over Entity Framework?

Comment: @abatishchev Because this is in legacy code that doesn't care how dead LINQ to SQL is ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it in memory, first fetch the records from db and apply the function you want:

```
query.AsEnumerable().First(...);
```

BTW, you might wanna use `FirstOrDefault` instead because this will throw an exception if there is no record found.

Comment: It might be useful to do some part of the query in db before fetching: `query.Where(f => f.MD5 == md5 || f.ArchiveFiles.Any(af => af.MD5 == md5)).AsEnumerable().First(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.FileName) == f.GraphicRequest.GraphicName)` to avoid fetching whole table.

Comment: @tdragon yes, that's correct. that would be really useful especially if there are too many records.